# andengine setPosition not working

Tags: java, android, andengine

I have tried the following code but when I click on mMan1 the second time to move it from 520 to 422(in x), it does nothing (when I click for the first time, setPosition works fine).

```
    \\ in onCreateScene
    mLine1 = new Sprite(422, 321, this.mLine,
            getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    mLine2 = new Sprite(274, 321, this.mLine,
            getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    scene.attachChild(mLine1);
    Button bu1 = new Button(1, 139, 174, this.mButtonTextureRegion,
            getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {

        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float X,
                float Y) {
            if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()) {
                scene.attachChild(mLine1);
                scene.detachChild(mLine2);
                mLine1.setVisible(true);
                mLine2.setVisible(false);
                setC(true);
                if (b == false || mMan1.getX() == 277) {
                    mMan1.setPosition(422, 249);
                    setB(false);
                }
            }
            return true;
        };

    };

    Button bu2 = new Button(2, 500, 174, this.mButtonTextureRegion,
            getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {

        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float X,
                float Y) {
            if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()) {
                scene.attachChild(mLine2);
                scene.detachChild(mLine1);
                mLine1.setVisible(false);
                mLine2.setVisible(true);
                setC(false);
                if (b == false || mMan1.getX() == 422) {
                    mMan1.setPosition(277, 249);
                    setB(false);
                }
            }
            return true;
        };

    };

    mMan1 = new Man(3, 520, 249, this.mMan, getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {

        @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float X,
                float Y) {
            if (pSceneTouchEvent.isActionUp()) {
                if (mMan1.getX() == 520 && c == true) {
                    mMan1.setPosition(422, 249);
                    setB(false);
                } else if (mMan1.getX() == 238 && c == false) {
                    mMan1.setPosition(277, 249);
                    setB(false);
                }
                if (mMan1.getX() == 422 && mLine2.isVisible() == false
                        && mLine1.isVisible() == true && b == false) {
                    mMan1.setPosition(520, 249);
                    setB(true);
                }
                if (mMan1.getX() == 277 && mLine1.isVisible() == false
                        && mLine2.isVisible() == true && b == false) {
                    mMan1.setPosition(238, 249);
                    setB(true);
                }
            }
            return true;

        };

    };
```

Boolean 'b' and 'c' are by default, true.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your conditions.

Possible scenarios:

1st click: mMan1 > it moves from 520 to 422 in X

2nd click: mMan1 > 1st and 2nd 'if' won't execute because of position, 3rd and 4th won't execute because of line.isVisible()

.............

1st click: bu1 > one line is not visible and one is visible. Position of player is not changed

2nd click: mMan1 > 1st 'if' will set the position to 422 in X, and then (because you've written 'if' instead of 'else if') next 'if' will execute because X is 422 and lines condition is true. The position will be set back to 522 so you can't see it.

.............

If you start with bu2 instead of bu1 nothing will happen for the second time because lines condition will be true for last 'if' but position won't be equal to 277.

PS it's much more clear if you use:

```
mLine2.isVisible()
```

instead of

```
mLine2.isVisible() == true
```

for booleans (! - for false).

You should check your 'if's and 'else if's. I guess you mean 'else if' in this case.

PS2 If you're happy with the solution mark my post as an answer and vote for it please (tick and up-arrow):)